# iOS6 multi route audio

Tags: ios, audio, hardware, routes

iOS 6.0 brought "multi-route audio" support to the iPhone / iPad.

DJay app for example benefits of it by allowing the user to hear one deck in headphones while playing the other.

The only mention of it is in the AVAudioSession class reference :

> AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute
> Allows you to output distinct streams of audio data to different output devices at the same time. For example, you would use this category to route audio to both a USB device and a set of headphones. Use of this category requires a more detailed knowledge of, and interaction with, the capabilities of the available audio routes.
>
> This category may be used for input, output, or both.
>
> Available in iOS 6.0 and later.

How to route two distinct streams to different routes ? Especially using Remote I/O ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Answering to myself : there's actually no information in iOS Developer Library, but hopefully, there's all the info needed in WWDC developer sessions.

Search for: WWDC 2012 Session 505: Audio Session and Multiroute Audio in iOS by Torrey Holbrook Walker.

I hope that may help somebody else.

Comment: Yes it does! :-) Thanks. I wouldn't have found it otherwise.